# jquery button align right beside asp dropdown

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to show my jquery button on the same line as my dropdown, currently it is beneath, I tried setting the inline width on Div but nothing happened , any advice ?

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblError"></asp:Label>
<div id="divChangeLabApproval" runat="server">
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblNewLabStatus" runat="server" Text="New Lab Status:&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSetLabStatus" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveLabChange" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="if (!OnSaveLabChangeClick()) return false;" OnClick="OnSaveLabChange" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any specific CSS that is being applied to these? As it looks like [they are all appearing on the same line to me](http://i.imgur.com/L9b0ckK.png)...

Comment: Yes but its to small the style for the div is too small so i tried pixels to make it wider but it did nothing , maybe there is a style blocking it you think ?